# Pgf set shade color

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is asking about a command code and i don't have a specific MWE.

I use `\pgfsetfillcolor{cyan}` to fill background of the beamer slide. But this command only gives me one color, cyan. Can i have a command code for shading?
Maybe something like `\pgfsetshadecolor{bottom color=cyan,top color=yellow}`
I want to fill something with bottom shade cyan and top shade yellow.

Thanks.

Comment: A `beamer` document with a single frame and how you use `\pgfsetfillcolor` might work as an MWE I suppose. Are low level `pgf` commands required in that context? If so, have you looked at section 114.3 *Using shadings* in the `pgf`/TikZ manual?

Comment: See `beamer`'s user manual (v3.59), sec. 8.2.7 _The Background_.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I use that command not in my tex document but as a sty document. I'm working on beamerthemeBoadilla.sty

Comment: It is more helpful, if you post a `MWE`....

Comment: You can probably put (the relevant) parts from the sty file in the preamble of a document (possibly between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`) and make a MWE that way.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you, it solved my problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is resolved in the comments.